# TypeScript signature of Promise#catch onrejected handler

Tags: typescript, promise

I notice the standard typing for `Promise#catch` in [`es6-shim.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts) is defined as

```
interface Promise<T> {
  catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<T>;
  catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => void): Promise<T>;
}
```

I am wondering why this is written this way, instead of as

```
catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T> | void): Promise<T>;
```

Some other file [`es6-promise.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts) by Nate Archibald gives a single signature of

```
catch<U>(onRejected?: (error: any) => U | Thenable<U>): Promise<U>;
```

not referring to `<T>` at all.

So is the second overloaded signature in `es6.shim-d-ts`, which as far as I know is in heavy use in a compile-to-ES5 environment, unnecessary/undesirable?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `T` can be `void` which means your use case is already supported.

If you did `T | PromiseLike<T> | void` the output might have been a `Promise<string>` that's resolved with `void` which would be a type error.

Note that promises aren't statically typed in a strong way in these definitions. The signature is actually harder since `reason` is typed `any`. This is like most languages (like C#) that sport unchecked exceptions and unlike Java and Swift which feature checked exceptions (a part of the signature of a function is what it might throw).

Comment: Are you saying it should actually be `catch(onrejected?: (reason: any) => void): Promise<void>`? I'm not sure where the `T` comes from anyway.

Comment: Or probably it really should be a union between the receiver promise's type argument and the callback return type, but that might be too complicated.

Comment: @Bergi T is a generic parameter of the promise - it can be anything and the constraint keeps it the same thing in the chain. I'm saying it should actually be `Promise<T,S>` if we want to be precise where S is for rejection and `then` should be then::Promise<T,E> -> ((T -> Promise<S, E2> | S) | undefined) | E -> Promise<S, E2> | S) | undefined) -> Promise<S,E2>` which is still not accurate but more "safe" - obviously that would be too complicated for our own good :)

Comment: @Bergi (addressing second comment which I didn't see when I wrote my reply) yeah, exactly

Comment: Would typescript support something like `Promise<T|S, E2>` at all?

Comment: @Bergi yes, it would - typescript is clever like that.